# is time based log level change possible in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

At first I was searching on how to change logging level without restarting server. I found solution using spring boot actuator. This solution is very good.

**But my actual doubt is**: What if we forget to re-change back to same logging level as before?

***For eg***: I've changed logging level to **DEBUG** from **ERROR** for some package "**com.demo**" using Actuator, but I forgot to revert back it again, so that means logging level **remains as DEBUG** forever for package **com.demo** unless service got restarted. Is this actually not a problem in Production environment? (I mean this effects performance, right?) So, any solution for this issue?

Comment: Why would you ever run something in production as debug? Debug is for testing purposes in test environments.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf So, we should add Actuator dependency only for Testing environments?

Comment: @ThomasAndolf I am using Maven, Do I need to add Actuator Dependency under <Profiles> in pom.xml file?

Comment: I think @john is searching for a solution which will automatically set the log level to default  (WARN) after certain period of time . You can write a cron job which will check log levels are appropriate or not after particular interval of time.

Comment: yes but ideally as mentioned by @ThomasAndolf , it is not recommended to use debug in production .

Comment: Not recommended BUT sometimes needed if you need more information on an issue which you cannot reproduce somewhere else. Also the fact that you don't want/need to logging endpoint in production doesn't mean you need to forgo everything of the actuator functionality. Things like metrics, health, etc. are still useful, especially in production.

Comment: Actuators have nothing to do with debugging. Actuators are used for monitoring status and general statistics of applications (keep the lights on) I never mentioned anything about actuator, I am talking about debugging. Setting something to debug does so much more then just enable logging. It produces generally more overhead in the entire application because the application can't optimize as much as it needs. If you can't reproduce something from production, then you should resolve why you cant reproduce it instead of adding on more bad practices and technical debt that you clearly already have

Answer (score 0):

`<Profiles>`
`<Profile>Testing environment</Profile>`
`<Profile>production environment</Profile>`
`</Profiles>`
I think you can add Actuator Dependency under Testing environment  in pom.xml file.

Comment: Don't, please don't. Don't rebuild an artifact just because you need it in a different environment. Just disable the endpoints you don't need in production. Actuator is more then just enable.disable logging it provides production features like metrics, health etc. as well.